# R: How to check a package's GitHub details

Tags: r, github-api

I'm trying to get **packrat** to recognise a package installed from GitHub whose URL has changed.

In previous versions of base R, `library(help = "packagename")` would reveal documentation that includes details of the remote repository such as the API site, GitHub user, repository name for a package installed from GitHub.

Current versions only show abridged information. Is there another function (or even a package) that I can use to get what I need? The challenge has been piecing together a Google query that can yield the right results

Answer (score 1):

I was able to arrive at the answer with the help of a Redditor:

The information I was looking for is only obtainable via the GitHub API. Thus, I removed the package and reinstalled it from GitHub. On checking it again, as before, with `library` I can now see the other fields. They include `GithubUsername`, `GithubRepo`, `RemoteHost`, etc.